# OpenX replaces "&" symbol in Google Analytics tracking URL

Tags: google-analytics, openx

I'm using OpenX platform for ad placement. When I upload flash banner which contains URL with campaign tracking parameters ( URL is build with Google Analytics URL builder tool ), for example :

```
http://example.com/somepage?utm_source=SourceName&utm_medium=banner&utm_content=SomeText&utm_campaign=Free+banner
```

After clicking on the banner I saw the following URL in the address bar -

```
http://example.com/somepage?utm_source=SourceName&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_content=SomeText&amp;utm_campaign=Free+banner
```

So all "`&`" have been replaced by "`&amp;`"

When I'm looking to the GA report, this link has been tracked as *Medium - (not set), Source - SourceName*. The rest parameters was ignored.

I've tried to use %26 instead of & . In this case GA tracks the link in a following way

*Medium - (not set), Source - SourceName&utm_medium=banner&utm_content=SomeText&utm_campaign=Free+banner *

I've tried not to hardcode the link to the flash banner, and set it from the OpenX, unfortunately in this case banner is not clickable.

Thank you in advance,

Stepan

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I found one solution of this issue. While adding banner with OpenX, I was always uploading backup image for the cases when the banner itself could not be shown. But when I try to skip this point. Problem with replacement of `&` with `&amp;` disappeared and now I can track campaign with GA.

However I still don;t know how to fix this problem if I need to use backup image.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with using the clickTAG FlashVars variable?  You need to set up the button in your Flash file to look for that FlashVars variable.

Here's a link to an old article discussing how to implement that:

http://web.archive.org/web/20130315080057/http://www.openx.com/docs/tutorials/Using+Flash+with+OpenX

Let me know if you need any other explanation or help, I hope this helps you going forward!